# Problems with linux Imagemagick converting PDFs to JPGs

Tags: linux, pdf, jpeg, postscript

The system I'm using uses the linux utility convert to convert pdfs to jpgs. My box gives me the following error.

```
>$ convert Badge-1114044091.pdf Badge-1114044091.jpg
convert: Postscript delegate failed `Badge-1114044091.pdf'.
convert: missing an image filename `Badge-1114044091.jpg'.
```

But the production machine does not. According to

```
>$ convert -version
```

my version is the same as the prodution machine. I'm not sure exactly how to check if postscript needs to be updated. Not really a huge linux guru.

**EDIT:** Upon suggestion, I checked Ghostscript. The following was already installed.

```
>$ gs -version
ESP Ghostscript 8.15.3 (2006-08-25)
Copyright (C) 2004 artofcode LLC, Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install GhostScript.

http://www.ghostscript.com/

---

ImageMagick (the 'convert' utility) doesn't actually convert PDFs; it invokes GhostScript using an arcane command like

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -r<OUTPUT RESOLUTION> -sOutputFile=<OUTPUT>.jpg <INPUT>.pdf 2>&1
```

You might want to try that command directly if you want more control.

Comment: This is the result of trying that command. Should I try reinstalling ghostscript?

>$ gs -q -sDEVICE=jpeg -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=Badge1008140412.jpg Badge1008140412.pdf 2>&1
Segmentation fault

Comment: Command works for me with gs version 8.63 (from Ubuntu repositories).

Comment: ...try without the -q option, see what is output before it dies.

Comment: ESP Ghostscript 815.03 (2006-08-25)
Copyright (C) 2004 artofcode LLC, Benicia, CA.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Segmentation fault

Not much more help...

Comment: Upgrading Ghostscript seemed to do the job. Accepting for leading me to Ghostscript.